# Exposed dirt under jetted tub smells after water leak

Tags: bathroom

In my bathroom I have a jetted tub and It recently leaked about 3 gallons of water after a fitting came lose.  Under the tub is just exposed dirt.  No concrete slab.   The problem is that the exposed dirt smells horrible after the water leak.  The exposed dirt has been bone dry for weeks but still smells.   I’ve sprayed bleach and other chemicals but nothing gets rid of the earthy / moldy smell.

I’ve thought of placing plastic over the dirt and covering it with gravel.

I would appreciate any help / advice.

Chris

Comment: what ventilation does the exposed dirt have?

Comment: Yuk bleach smells as bad as musky earth to me. I would make sure to dry the area with ventilation as @jason suggests and if things are still growing spray a 5-6% hydrogen peroxide. Hydrogen peroxide will not stink like bleach it will kill any organic organisms creating a smell and when done it converse back into oxygen and water no harmful byproducts compared to bleach.